# eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform in the Schwartz space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Recall that $L^2(\mathbb R)$ decomposes into the direct sum of the eigenspaces of the Fourier transform corresponding to its four eigenvalues, namely the four fourth roots of unity.  If $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ actually belongs to the  *Schwartz space*  of functions (namely $\|x^mf^{(n)}(x)\|_\infty$ is finite for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$), do the orthogonal projections of $f$ onto the four eigenspaces also lie in the Schwartz space?

Answer (score 7):

Let F denote the Fourier transform, and let f be a given function. Then consider the decomposition
$$f=(f_1+f_2+f_3+f_4)/4,$$
where
$$f_1=f+Ff+F^2f+F^3f,$$
$$f_2=f+iFf-F^2f-iF^3f,$$
$$f_3=f-Ff+F^2f-F^3f,$$
$$f_4=f-iFf-F^2f+iF^3f.$$

Comment: More generally: If $f:V\to V$ is an endomorphism and $P(X)=\prod_i (X-a_i)$ a polynomial with $P(f)=0$ and pairwise distince zeros $a_i$, then the projection onto the $a_i$-Eigenspace of $f$ is given by $\prod_{j\neq i} \frac{f-a_j}{a_i-a_j}$.